# How to align two div's with different max-width

Tags: html, css

I have an issue. I have two `div`'s among each other. Above the div with the image right and text left, and below the div with two text properties. Now my problem is that the div (section) on the top has an max width of 1920px but the image has to be align on the left side with the p tag in the section below. I added a sketch of what I mean. and of course a [codepen](https://codepen.io/melissa-bos/pen/RwGQWdK)

```css
.Hero {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .Hero {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
   }
 }

  @media screen and  (min-width: 64em) {
    .Hero {
      padding-top: 80px;
      padding-bottom: 80px;
    }
  }

.Hero-layout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.Hero-tekst {
   width: 280px;
   margin-right: 40px;
 }

.Hero-image {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 64em) {
  .Hero-layout {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 0;
   }
  .Hero-image {
    margin-top: 0
   }
 }

.PaginaIntro {
  max-width: 1320px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.PaginaIntro-heading {
  width: 280px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.PaginaIntro-tekst {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="Hero">
  <div class="Hero-layout">
    <div class="Hero-tekst">
      <h3>Bla bla</h3>
      <button>Play</button>
    </div>
    <img class="Hero-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="palm" />
  </div>
</section>

<section class="PaginaIntro">
  <h2 class="PaginaIntro-heading">Bla</h2>
  <p class="PaginaIntro-tekst">OLorem dollar ipsum OLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsum</p>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to swap the image with the `h3` and the `button`, right? Or you want to place everything on the same row, with the image on the left side and the text on the right side? If so, where does the button and the `h3` go?

Comment: @Daniel The image in the above section has to be vertical align with the text in the section below. See the stripe. Same goes for the left vertical align text containers

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to have a div for your image and your text, then with display inline-block choose the width of the 2 elements.

Here my code snippet, is this what you want to have ?
```

```css
  .hero{
      background: green;
      white-space: nowrap; 
  }
  .hero__layout{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40%;
      white-space: normal;
  }
  .hero__images{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 60%;
      white-space: normal;
  }
  .pagina{
      background: blue;
      white-space: nowrap; 
  }
  .pagina__intro{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  .pagina__content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    white-space: normal;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    


<section class="hero">
    <div class="hero__layout">
        <div class="hero__layout-text">
            <h3>Title 3</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero__images">
        <img class="Hero-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="palm" />
    </div>
</section>
<section class="pagina">
    <div class="pagina__intro">
        <h2 class="pagina__intro-heading">Title H2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pagina__content">
        <p class="pagina__content-text">
                Lorem dollar ipsum OLorem dollar ipsum
                Lorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar 
                ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar 
                ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar 
                ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsumOLorem dollar ipsum
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the layout you need. I've changed your classes a bit, but the idea behind is the same.

```css
.hero {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.hero-left img {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="hero-left">
    <div class="hero-cta">
      <h3>Some Title Here</h3>
      <button>CTA</button>
    </div>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
  </div>
  <div class="hero-right">
    <h2>Another Title Here</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

You can then edit the spacing and the sizes for the image and the paragraph section.